# Changing font size with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the font-size of the text in a textarea by using the .css attr but its not working, do you guys have any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function crap () {
    var text_input = $('#textarea').val();
    text_input.css("font-size", "14px");
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="textarea" rows="30" cols="70"> </textarea><br/><br/>
Font size:<input type="text" id="font_size"/> <input type="button" id="px" value="14px" onClick="crap()"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: function Crap().  I wish it was that simple

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function crap () {
    var text_input = $('#textarea');
    text_input.css("font-size", "14px");
}
```

Remove `.val`.  That will get the value within the textarea, you want to affect the textarea itself.

Comment: thanks very much, do you know how i can make the textarea fixed on changing the font-size?

Comment: I think you can do so, by adding a specific height and width attribute via css to the textarea in question.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#incfont').click(function(){   

        curSize= parseInt($('#content').css('font-size')) + 2;

  if(curSize<=200)

        $('#content').css('font-size', curSize);

        }); 

  $('#decfont').click(function(){   

        curSize= parseInt($('#content').css('font-size')) - 2;

  if(curSize>=12)

        $('#content').css('font-size', curSize);

        });

  $('#minheight').click(function(){   

        curSize= 16;

        $('#content').css('font-size', curSize);

        }); 

 });
```

Comment: I enclosed your code in tags, but you may want to add a little explanation to the answer.

Comment: A good answer is not one that works, it's one with the appropriate amount of documentation. The OP should **learn** something form an answer rather than just copy pasting it. That way he won't be back a week later asking the same question in a different context...

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
<style type="text/css">

#textarea
{
     font-size:14px;
}

</style>
```